# Using ENV variables in daemonized Docker running RStudio

Tags: r, git, docker, rstudio-server

I am able to set up a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ropensci/docker-ubuntu-r/blob/c393ce396008641ae35e0da6483025c30524b7a1/add-r-ropensci/Dockerfile) with default ENV variables that I can then configure when running my docker container, e.g. in a Dockerfile I have the lines:

```
ENV USERNAME ropensci
ENV EMAIL ropensci@github.com
RUN git config --global user.name $USERNAME
RUN git config --global user.email $EMAIL
```

Great.  When I launch an interactive session:

```
docker run -it --env USERNAME="Carl" --env EMAIL=cboettig@example.com myimage /bin/bash
```

I can then issue the command `git config --list` and see that git is configured to use the values I provided on the command line instead of the defaults.

However, my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ropensci/docker-ubuntu-r/blob/c393ce396008641ae35e0da6483025c30524b7a1/add-r-ropensci/Dockerfile) is also configured to run an RStudio server that I can then log into in the browser when running the image in Daemon mode:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 --env USERNAME="Carl" --env EMAIL=cboettig@example.com cboettig/ropensci-docker
```

I go to localhost:8787 and log in to RStudio which all works as expected, start a new "Project" with git enabled, but then RStudio cannot find my git name & email.  I can open the shell from the RStudio menu and run `git config --list` or `echo $USERNAME` and I just get a blank value.  Why does this work for /bin/bash but not from RStudio and how do I fix it?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/16867818/1205368

Comment: @Salem No go. Note this has nothing to do with accessing the environmental variables in R, since they are not available on the shell either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your git config is set on /.gitconfig. This config file is for root user. You need to set git config for rstudio user because rstudio run on rstudio user. Below command is a temporary solution.

```
docker run -it -p 8787:8787 --env USERNAME="Carl" --env EMAIL=cboettig@example.com cboettig/ropensci-docker bash -c "cp /.gitconfig /home/rstudio; /usr/bin/supervisord"
```

It works!

[image: rstudio]

Another solution is writing Dockerfile is based on cboettig/ropensci-docker. Below is sample Dockerfile.

```
FROM cboettig/ropensci-docker
RUN cp /.gitconfig /home/rstudio
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: Bingo, I shoulda noticed that! Dockerfile now updated as you suggested.  Thanks